# iPod Touch home button having issues

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

My iPod Touch home button recently started being less responsive. Any way to fix this, preferably without hardware changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this perhaps -- http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/12/22/recalibrate-home-button-responsive/?

Comment: Will try that now

Comment: Seemed to help. Placebo or not, i'm fine with it!

Comment: :-) Placebo effect can be good at times.